# How to reset a meteor project thats been deployed with meteor up

Tags: meteor, reset

I have used meteorUp [here](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up#reconfiguring--restarting) sucesffuly to deploy my meteor project on my own host.

However I have no idea how to **reset the database**, or the entire project itself, like I can locally with the simple meteor reset command. I tried installing meteor on the server but there is no .meteor project so that command doesnt work. I looked in /opt/meteor folder but no meteor project exists.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you need to reset the data. You need to login to the server. login to mongodb with `mongo meteor`.

Then do `db.dropDatabase()` to delete the DB.

If you need to change the app, simple redeploy should work.

> BTW: Do you not use MongoDB this way for a production app.

Comment: In what way are you referring you? Sorry just confused.

Comment: I mean, do no use mongodb installed server installed by mup in production. You need to enable backups and use replica sets. For that, easy way to use use some cloud provider like MongoHQ.

Comment: this won't work for mupx since the mongodb is inside the docker container right?

Answer (score 10):

If you are using [mup](https://github.com/kadirahq/meteor-up) or [mupx](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/tree/mupx) try:

**Login to your server**:

```
$ ssh <user>@<server-ip>
```

**Login into mongo shell**

```
$ docker exec -it mongodb mongo <app-name>
```

**Drop db**

```
> db.dropDatabase()
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
mup reconfig
```

Based on the [doc](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up#reconfiguring--restarting) for it:

> This will also restart the app [without re-deploying], so you can use it for that purpose
>   even if you didn't change the configuration file.

Comment: I tried that but all that does is restart, not reset the project.

Comment: The question was how to RESET a meteor project and not how to RESTART it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough points to comment yet, but to add onto Arunoda's response, you might want to

```
use [name of app database]
```

before you

```
db.dropDatabase()
```

And if you don't know what the name is you can also

```
show databases
```

If you used mup, the database will generally be the same name as your app.